# about annotate django

Tags: django, annotations

I'd like to create the top five best seller of the products in each month.

I've heard that the annotations must be used for this case but I don't know how to use it.

Will anybody be kind enough to help me ??

Comment: Give us your current code. If you don't have any, then most likely you'll answer your own question in the course of writing it.

Answer (score 7):

You need to provide much more information before anyone can provide you with a useful answer. Describe what you know, what you've tried, elaborate on what you hope to accomplish.

In the mean time, you can learn about django's [`annotate()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate-args-kwargs) function, and see a few examples by reading the [aggregation documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) for django.

Answer (score 5):

annotate is not the only way to do it.  You could also use an `extra` aggregation, though it might not be very efficient, and this will rely on sql specific to your database.  This approach will not work in App Engine, but should in a SQL compliant database.

For example, say you had a `Product` model and a `SalesOrder` model, where the `SalesOrder` model has a line item for each `product_id` and `order_date` in it.

```
top_products = Product.objects.extra( 
    select={'num_orders':'select count(product_id) from app_product where app_salesorder.order_date > thirty_days_ago and app_product.id = app_salesorder.product_id'})
        .order_by('-num_orders')[:5]
```